# Accessing memory-typed views in Cython is slow

Tags: performance, pointers, cython, typed-memory-views

I'm trying to create a custom version of numpy.argmin that goes over a 2D array and finds the minimum (it's a custom version because I have some domain-specific information numpy doesn't have, which will result in faster execution).

My first implementation was something like this:

```
cdef my_argmin(array):
    cdef double[:, ::1] mv = array  # I know the array is in C-order
    cdef int i, j, min_i, min_j
    cdef double tmp, min

    min = 1e50
    for i in range(1000):
        for j in range(1000):
            tmp = mv[i, j]
            if tmp < min: 
                min, min_i, min_j = tmp, i, j
    return (i,j)
```

This takes about twice as long as numpy's own argmin. The problem was with accessing the memory-view. It's slow. Once I added some pointers:

```
cdef double *row_ptr

for i in range(1000):
    row_ptr = &mv[i,0]
    for j in range(1000):
        tmp = row_ptr[j]
```

performance came close enough to numpy's argmin.

I noticed the same happening with 1-dimensional memory-typed views, requiring me to replace each one with a pointer before iterating it.

I have the following declaration at the top of my pyx file, just to make sure.

```
# cython: boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, nonecheck=False
```

Comment: try removing all compiler directives and timing it again.